# Change x-iframe-options on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, iframe

When I embed wordpress into iframe, then login and other pages not work. I see that is caused by x-iframe-opions of WP set to deny embed of iframe for security reason.

I found this solution but not work with last WP:

```
remove_action( 'admin_init', 'send_frame_options_header', 10, 0 );
remove_action( 'login_init', 'send_frame_options_header', 10, 0 );
```

I try also via htaccess but not work:

```
 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header set X-Frame-Options allow
   Header always append X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM http://domain.com"
 </IfModule>
```

I see that allow-from work only for certain browser, however I would like to allow if possible only for a certain domain, or from all domains.

Comment: Does the `.htaccess` approach work if you try to embed a non WP page? (like the _license.txt/readme_)

Comment: yes all pages work fine also without htaccess, it's only WP issue

Comment: only WP pages like login and similar

Comment: No solution ???

Comment: 6years later same error - how to remove the existing x-frame-option so it is not set multiple times?